# Why this code for anagram is not giving correct result only for ravi & vira?

Tags: c++, c++14

In this program i am trying to sort the string by their ASCII values by taking them as a integer. And then sort them in ascending order and check if they have the same set of elements

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int len(int a[]){
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)
        l++;
    return l;    
}
int len_str(string a){
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)
        l++;
    return l;    
}
void asc_order(int a[]){
    int n=len(a), temp=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            if(a[i]<a[j]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
}

int main(){
    system("cls");
    string str1, str2;
    cout<<"Enter the first string  : ";
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout<<"Enter the second string : ";
    getline(cin, str2);
    string res = "YES";
    if(len_str(str1)==len_str(str2)){
        int n = len_str(str1);
        int ch1[n], ch2[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            ch1[i] = str1[i];
            ch2[i] = str2[i];
        }
        asc_order(ch1);
        asc_order(ch2);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            if(ch1[i]!=ch2[i])
                res = "NO";
    }
    else
        res = "NO"; 
    cout<<res;
}
```

It gives NO as the res when str1 and str2 are *ravi* and *vira* respectively.

Comment: `int ch1[n];` -s not standard C++

Comment: `#include<string>` instead of `#include<string.h>`. You don't use any C-string functions but you use `std::string`.

Comment: Why do you use `len_str(str1)` instead of `str1.length()`? You don't need `int ch1[n], ch2[n];`. You can `std::sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());`

Comment: What this code supposed to do?

Comment: After I removed all the unnecessary stuff it works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/okguHOz3D5uTSEkJ

Comment: simplified https://godbolt.org/z/cqKxx4

Comment: Aayush Gupta: Didn't any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your sort.

I removed most of the unnecessary code and kept your sort logic ([working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9RriTBL6M91VURfo)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void asc_order(string a){
    char temp=0;
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < a.length() ; i++)
        for(std::size_t j=0; j < a.length(); j++)
            if(a[i]<a[j]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
}

int main(){
    string str1, str2;
    cout<<"Enter the first string  : ";
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout<<"Enter the second string : ";
    getline(cin, str2);
    string res = "YES";
    if(str1.length() == str2.length()) {
        asc_order(str1);
        asc_order(str2);
        for(std::size_t i=0; i < str1.length(); i++)
            if(str1[i] != str2[i])
                res = "NO";
    }
    else
        res = "NO"; 
    cout<<res;
}
```

It returns wrong result `NO`.

Then I replaced your sort with `std::sort` ([working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Um7UmIQ6i02AL7j7)):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str1, str2;
    cout<<"Enter the first string  : ";
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout<<"Enter the second string : ";
    getline(cin, str2);
    string res = "YES";
    if(str1.length() == str2.length()) {
        std::sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
        std::sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());
        for(std::size_t i=0; i < str1.length(); i++)
            if(str1[i] != str2[i])
                res = "NO";
    }
    else
        res = "NO"; 
    cout<<res;
}
```

It works: `YES`

Answer (score 1):

Your `asc_order` function will swap two entries whether they're in the right order or the wrong order.

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length() ; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<a.length(); j++)
        if(a[i]<a[j]){
```

Since both `i` and `j` run the full range of the string's length, the test if `a[i]<a[j]` will sometimes test if they're in the right order and sometimes test if they're in the wrong order since `i` may be less than or greater than `j`.

Maybe you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length() ; i++)
    for(int j=i; j<a.length(); j++)
        if(a[i]<a[j]){
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really this line:

```
int ch1[n], ch2[n];
```

Aside from that not being valid C++ (g++ allows dynamic sized arrays), it's creating a table the length of the string, not the full range of ascii.   Your strings might only be 10 chars long, but 'a' has a value of 97.  So it's out of range and you're into undefined behavior territory.   Also, you don't need to define your own length functions. That's already built into the C++ string class.

Change this stuff:

```
if(len_str(str1)==len_str(str2)){
    int n = len_str(str1);
    int ch1[n], ch2[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ch1[i] = str1[i];
        ch2[i] = str2[i];
    }
    asc_order(ch1);
    asc_order(ch2);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(ch1[i]!=ch2[i])
            res = "NO";
}
else
    res = "NO";
```

To be this:

```
char map1[256]={};  // you can use CHAR_BIT*sizeof(char) instead of a hardcoded 256
char map2[256]={};
for (char c : str1)
{
    map1[(unsigned char)c]++;
}
for (char c : str2)
{
    map2[(unsigned char)c]++;
}
int result = memcmp(map1, map2, sizeof(map1)); // returns 0 if the memory contents are the same. include <string.h> to get this function.
res = result ? "NO" : "YES";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the size of my array to 100 instead of n and it worked like a charm!!

Comment: Why would limiting your array to 100 instead of 256 fix anything?  The moment any char at letter `d` (ascii value 100) or higher appears in `str1` or `str2`, you've corrupted your program.